# Call php function from bash - with arguments

Tags: php, bash, function, shell, call

I have a simple **func.php** file with *concat* function:

```
<?php
function concat($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return $arg1.$arg2;
    }
?>
```

I would like to call this function from linux bash shell with two arguments :

```
1st: "Hello, "
2nd: "World!"
```

and print the output ("Hello, World!") to linux bash shell.

Please tell me, how to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

So for example, your script would be called like this:

`php /path/to/script.php 'Hello, ' 'World!'`

Then in your PHP file:

```
<?php
$arg1 = $argv[1];
$arg2 = $argv[2];

echo concat($arg1, $arg2);

function concat($arg1, $arg2) {
    return $arg1 . $arg2;
}
```