# Invoke a PHP method using bash script

Tags: php, bash

I want to invoke a method using bash script.

Code:

```
class ABC {
    public static function methodABC(){
        //My logic 
        echo "Done";
    }
}
```

That is my code when I am trying this using command line I am getting class fatal error.

```
php -r 'include "./src/ABC.php"; ABC::methodABC();'
```

Error:

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ABC' not found in Command line code:1
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
>   thrown in Command line code on line 1
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call php function from bash - with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090760/call-php-function-from-bash-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `ABC.php` needs to start with `<?php`.

When executing code with `-r`, only the code passed as an argument doesn't need tags, not the code in the included file.

Comment: inside my methodABC method i'm checking `class_exists` function but its not finding existed classes also

Comment: That's a different problem, that is not demonstrated with your code.